# Update many to many relationship having ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 model with many to many relationship:

```
Movie
Person
MovieToPerson
```

Say I have a single person and I want to update the list of movies they star in. For movies I have ids. How can I do that?

```
pers = Person.first
movie_ids = get_movies_ids
pers.movies = ....????
```

I want to avoid querying the movie objects before updating.

Comment: Is that Simple Join or Rich Join, I mean in your Joining Table have you defined more fields other than the two foreign keys?

Comment: @ehsan, only 2 for. keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can try autosave on belongs_to relation,

> 4.1.2.1 :autosave
>
> If you set the :autosave option to true, Rails will save any loaded
>   members and destroy members that are marked for destruction whenever
>   you save the parent object.